# Paid sites OK or not?

Tags: discussion, scope

Just seeking clarification about the following:

[Is there a web application to check English?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/440/is-there-a-web-application-to-check-english/514#514)

and

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/484/are-there-any-online-ocr-services/488#488

What's the policy about pay-for online services? Someone downvoted the OCR service which is pay-for, but it seems like a legitimate answer to me. Is webapps.stackexchange.com all about free applications only, or is pay-for OK too?

Answer (score 15):

I'm pretty sure that paid sites are more than okay. It's just one of the problems you run into when people ask these poll type questions. People don't treat down votes the same. Essentially they are using it as "I don't like this product" instead of the usual "this isn't a valid answer". You shouldn't take it personally, it's just that they want to see their favorite service on top.

Comment: yah, voting is just .. voting. if 1000 people just like the app (lets say 'backpack' and one user is voting it down .. then its still a pretty popular webapp. how the webapp is making money is not the scope of webapp, so your answer is very legitimate.

Answer (score 7):

I think recommending paid services is fine, but you should probably mention that it's not free in your answer. People will probably automatically assume that it's free otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Free sites often go out of business. Someone has to pay the developers and bandwidth bills.  I'd say answers involving paid sites have certain advantages.

Answer (score 0):

Paid web applications should be allowed.